# Angular directive this and closure issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I have such directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[imgTest]',
})
export class ImgTest implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  private originalImage: HTMLImageElement;
  private secondImage: HTMLDivElement;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  @HostListener('load')
  public onLoad(): void {
    this.process();
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.originalImage = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.removeEventListeners();
  }

  private addEventListeners(): void {
    this.originalImage.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveImage);
    this.secondImage.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveImage);
  }

  private removeEventListeners(): void {
    this.originalImage.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.moveImage);
    this.secondImage.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.moveImage);
  }

  private process(): void {
    if (!this.originalImage) {
      return;
    }

    /* some magic */

    this.addEventListeners();
  }

  private moveImage(e: MouseEvent): void {
    let pos: { x: number; y: number }, x: number, y: number;
    e.preventDefault();
    /* some magic that is using also this.getPos(e) */
  }

  private getPos(e: MouseEvent): { x: number; y: number } {
    /* some magic */

    return { x: x, y: y };
  }
}
```

and the issue is that inside `moveImage` **this** is wrong and it's just not working at all.
what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are adding a listener like this

```
this.originalImage.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveImage);
```

you are basically breaking "this" reference.

to preserve correct "this" it you could add a listener in an other way - you should create another callback which would call the method in the correct context

```
this.originalImage.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => this.moveImage(e));
// or
this.originalImage.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveImage.bind(this));
// or
boundMoveImage = this.moveImage.bind(this) // somewhere inside of a class
...
...addEventListener('mousemove', this.boundMoveImage); // this way you could removeEventListeners in remove callbacks
```

Comment: The problem with the solution you suggested is that he can no longer remove the listeners without storing it globally in the class. This is why it has to be bound in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It's because inside the `addEventListener`, `this` keyword doesn't refer to the class. You should modify your code to the following:

```js
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.moveImage = this.moveImage.bind(this);
  }
```

After binding `moveImage`, it will work as expected